# _popen in windows with both stdout and stdin

Tags: c, windows

How to popen with both stdin and stdout in windows in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little more complicated as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN article shows.

Comment: Can you please explain why it doesn't work? The child process is only required to read/write from/to stdin/stdout. You don't have to somehow implement the sample program from that page.

Answer (score 3):

A sample is given in the following article. It is quite long-winded but you can cut out the relevant parts.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351